# Simple Json from RESTful query - unable to Deserialize

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest

I am REST/JSON newbie and I am querying Feedzilla API for news articles, with keyword *syria*:

http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q=syria

```
    public FZResult Search(string query)
    {
        //_client.BaseUrl = string.Format("http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json}", StackExchangeSite);
        _client.BaseUrl = string.Format("http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json");

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

        //Required
        request.AddParameter("q", "syria");

        //Output
        RestResponse response = (RestResponse)_client.Execute(request);

        IDeserializer deserializer;
        deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();

        //The format that Wikipedia uses
        deserializer.DateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";

        FZResult results = deserializer.Deserialize<FZResult>(response);

        return results;
    }
```

`FZResult` class looks like this:

```
 public class FZResult
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "items")]
        public List<ResultItem> Items { get; set; }

    }
```

My `ResultItem` class looks like this:

```
  public class ResultItem
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "url")]
        public string url { get; set; }

    }
```

However, the `FZResult` from `Search()` method above returns `null`. I have checked the JSON is properly formed and able to parse it fine - I am sure it has something to do with the class definitions & `DeserializeAs`...

Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the `FZResult` class. If you look at the json returned from the service, the root element is an array called `articles`. You class has `[DeserializeAs(Name = "items")]`, this would probably confuse the deserialization engine, since the `Name` should be `articles`.

Try changing these values and check the new result.

Regrettably I haven't tried RestSharp. The code below uses `Newtonsoft.JSON` and a regular `HttpWebRequest` to get the result. I have confirmed it to be working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace FeedZilla
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/26/articles/search.json?q=syria");

            using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var fzResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FZResult>(reader.ReadToEnd());

                    fzResult.Articles.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a.Title, a.Url));
                }
            }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class FZResult
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "articles")]
            public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        }

        public class Article
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try changing to 'articles'. No dice :-/

Comment: strange. Which json serializer are you using?

Comment: Restsharp. That deserializer works fine for other queriesI am performing. (e.g. Stackexchange)

Comment: Sorry, don't know that one. I have provided example code with a hand coded request and a Newtonsoft.JSON deserialization. Hope it can be of some value to you.

Comment: awesome, thanks much for the quick help. Been tearing my hair with this sh*t. Very Much appreciated!!